# Playing Iframe video only when visible in Viewport (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to make a webpage containing two videos:

Each video should only be played when visible in the viewport.

I have used a jquery function which detects when a video is in the viewport, plays the video when it is in view and pauses the video when the video is outside of the viewport.

I have made a simple webpage to demonstrate this and so far, this functionality only seems to be working for the first of the two videos:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.xx.x/css/uikit.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.xx.x/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="inner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="innercontainer">
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="videocontainer">
    <div>
   <iframe id="video1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/757127483?background=true" width="920" height="200" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>
   <iframe id="video2" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/807516670?background=true" width="920" height="200" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <img>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
    <script>
var players = []
$('.inner').each(function() {
  players.push({
      player: new Vimeo.Player($(this).find("iframe").get(0)),
      top: $(this).position().top,
      status: "paused"
  })
});
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    for(var i=0; i<players.length;i++) {
        var elementFromTop = players[i].top - scrollPos;
      var status = (elementFromTop > 0 && elementFromTop < players[i].top + viewportHeight) ? "pause" : "play";   
      if(players[i].status != status) {
          players[i].status = status;
          players[i].player[status]();
          console.log(i, status);      
      }
    }
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone spot why the functionality is only working for the first video iframe and not the second one ?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75856004/autoplay-iframe-only-when-video-is-visible

Comment: No, there are subtle differences in the language and syntax of the question which mean that it should be asked as an entirely separate question, you just didn't pick up on them.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are only adding one iframe to the `players` array.

```js
$('.inner').each(function() {
  players.push({
      player: new Vimeo.Player($(this).find("iframe").get(0)),
      top: $(this).position().top,
      status: "paused"
  })
});
```

Should be replaced with:

```js
$("iframe").each((index) => {
  players.push({
    player: new Vimeo.Player($("iframe").get(index)),
    top: $("iframe").eq(index).position().top,
    status: "paused",
  });
});
```

You should be iterating through all of the iframes, not through ".inner". Otherwise, the loop will only run once.

Another note, in your code:

```js
var status = (elementFromTop > 0 && elementFromTop < players[i].top + viewportHeight) ? "pause" : "play";
```

"pause" and "play" should be switched.

```js
var status = (elementFromTop > 0 && elementFromTop < players[i].top + viewportHeight) ? "play" : "pause";
```

You can see a live example of this working here: https://4ofuxh.csb.app/

I hope I have answered your question :)

Comment: Excellent solution, well done -- Just a small issue though - when the viewport reaches video 1: Video 1 AND Video 2 start playing... do you know if you can change the function so that only Video 1 starts playing when viewport reaches video 1, and then video 2 when the viewport reaches video 2 ?

Comment: Only both videos will play if the screen size is big enough to fit both of them, which is what is supposed to happen.

Comment: At the moment the second video is playing when the first video comes into view - even if the second video is off the page - do you know how to fix that ?